# git submodules empty after git clone --recursive repo_url

Tags: git, git-submodules

Summary: git clone --recursive REPO works, but doesn't checkout a commit for the submodules, instead it leaves all submodules empty.

I run

> git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:user/repo.git
>   Cloning into 'repo'...

However, when I cd into repo,

> git status

returns

```
modified:   submodule1 (new commits, modified content)
modified:   submodule2 (modified content)
modified:   submodule3 (modified content)
```

Running ls in any of the submodule folders shows they are all empty.

If I run "git status" on any of the submodule folders, it shows that all the contents have been deleted.

I can still checkout master (or any other commits) from any of the submodules, which restores the submodule.

My impression is that the command "git clone --recursive" is supposed to download and checkout the submodules.

git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
hub version 2.2.9

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `git clone --recursive git@github.com:dahlia/libsass-python` w/ git 2.7.4 -- do you have a *specific* repository this fails on?

Comment: It's failed twice so far with two of my own github repositories, both in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

There was an error in one of the submodules, it was missing the referenced commit, and so the command stopped midway through.